# Convert date to milliseconds in batchscript

Tags: windows, batch-file

How to find date 30 days before from currentdate?
How to convert date to milliseconds?
Using batch script.

Please help me on this. Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

This is a VBS script inside a batch file.

```
:: date 30 days ago
@echo off
set day=-30
echo >"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" s=DateAdd("d",%day%,now) : d=weekday(s)
echo>>"%temp%\%~n0.vbs" WScript.Echo year(s)^& right(100+month(s),2)^& right(100+day(s),2)
for /f %%a in ('cscript /nologo "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"') do set "result=%%a"
del "%temp%\%~n0.vbs"
set "YYYY=%result:~0,4%"
set "MM=%result:~4,2%"
set "DD=%result:~6,2%"
set "date-then=%yyyy%-%mm%-%dd%"

echo The date then was "%date-then%"
pause
```

Comment: Can you please tell me How to convert date to milliseconds?

Comment: It might overflow the 2^31 limit in batch math.

Answer (score 0):

Working with date and time is difficult using only native Windows batch commands, especially if you are dealing with large numbers as can be found with time stamps expressed as milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC.

As foxidrive has demonstrated, the computations are easy using VBScript (or JScript).

I have written a [hybrid JScript/batch utility called getTimestamp.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4847) that makes it very easy to work with dates and times in batch scripts. The utility is pure script that will run natively on any modern Windows machine from XP onward. Full documentation is embedded within the utility.

**Get date 30 days prior to today (local time) and store it in DT variable**

```
call getTimestamp -od -30 -f {yyyy}-{mm}-{dd} -r DT
```

You didn't specify a date format. The utility supports nearly any format you could ever want.

**Get current date/time expressed as milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC and store in TS variable**

```
call getTimestamp -f {ums} -r TS
```

Note: I suspect that JScript time computations may not account for leap seconds. So the value may not be 100% accurate.

**If you want the time stamp of 30 days before today's date at midnight (local time), expressed as milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000 UTC and store in TS variable**

```
call getTimestamp -od -30 -f {mm}/{dd}/{yyyy} -r DT
call getTimestamp -d '%DT%' -F {ums} -r TS
```

---

There are ***many*** options to the utility. Enter `getTimestamp -?` from the command prompt to get full documentation.